# Can I create a template from a list?

Tags: list, content-type, document-template

Can I generate a word template, containing information from a list?

Suppose I have a list containing "department addresses", and I want to generate letter heads for each department automatically, containing the correct address.

This way, if an address changes, I only have to adjust the info in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. But, this requires you to configure a document library to use your departmental templates for creating new documents such as Letterheads other 'pre-defined' templates etc.

1. Define your base templates? Ask yourself question if you need to reuse
   this template in another site etc?
2. Create your custom Content Types within the site they will be used. Choose an appropriate Parent Content Type (often you’ll choose ‘*Document*’)
3. Take the Document Templates (base templates for e.g. *.docx*) and
   attach/upload them to your Custom Content Type.
4. Configure your document library to **Manage content types**
5. Add your custom content types to the document library. Voila!

Comment: I don't think this is the answer I am looking for.
I want to create a different letterhead for each address in the list.
Also, the link posted here yesterday looked promising, but it was removed?

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2008/10/29/merging-sharepoint-list-data-into-word-documents.aspx, 
solved my problem!

Comment: If this was your preferred solution please add some details as to how this helped you (external links to blogs tend to die fast), and mark it as answer